# Is a ova file interchangable between Oracle's VirtualBox and VMware's player?

Tags: vmware, virtualization, virtual-machine, virtualbox

It seems to be easy question but I an new at this. I got a ova from one of my partners. He told me he exported a VM file using `Export Appliance` in VirtualBox. And my office's laptop is installed with VM player. My guess is that it is the same ova filetype. It supposed to open in both VMs. However, VW play shows this message.

> Failed to open virtual machine: Failed to query source for information.

Any thought on this?

Comment: Have the same issue .. tried the export from VirtualBox with "Create legacy OVF 0.9" and/or "Create manifest" turned on. Same problem, same error message.